# PHP Include a page based on multiple parameters rather than just one

Tags: php, html

I have this code on my index page:

```
if(isset($_GET['source'])){
    $source = $_GET['source'];
} else {
    $source = "";
}

switch($source) {
    case 'credits';
        include "includes/credits.php";
        break;

    default:
        include "includes/recommended.php";
        break;
}
```

Linked with this HTML

```
<li class="listp sp"> <a href="index.php?id=3?source=credits" class="sli">Credits</a></li>
```

If the `href="index.php?source=credits"`, then `credits.php` will be included, but if I add an additional parameter (say `id=3`) then the page will not work. How do I make it so that I can include the `credits.php` file when I have multiple parameters, and just the `source=credits` parameter alone?

For example, I want the id to be different depending on the user, but I want to access the page whether there is an `d (user logged in) or not(user not logged in).

Comment: The two included pages should act on the id on their own.

Comment: The answer is correct, you would see this if you `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Why dont use one pattern for your files and create a dinamic import basead on thia pattern?

Comment: you have used incorrect path. Replace ? with & like this: <a href="index.php?id=3&source=credits" class="sli">Credits</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your URL using the url parameter separator `&`, not `?`, which is not a valid URL format

```
<a href="index.php?id=3&source=credits" class="sli">Credits</a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Comment: I completely thought that the ? mark is used to include another parameter, thanks for pointing that out